# m Prefix for Android Development in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I know this question has been asked many times, but the answers are several years old at this point.

Is it still recommended to use the `m` prefix for member variables when developing for Android in Android Studio, or in general?

As you can you see from the following image taken from Android Studio, the member variables `question` and `trueQuestion` are clearly visually distinguished from the local variable `someLocalVaribale`. To me it would appear unnecessary to include the `m` prefix but I wanted to hear thoughts from more experienced developers.

[image]

Comment: This is purely a style question. Android is written in Java. Java has a couple popular style guides for writting code. Prefixing and 'm' is up to you. Just because your id helps distinguish it doesn't mean everyone who may want to use your code is going to use the same IDE. Keep a consistent style across all your apps, whether that is prefixing an 'm' or not

Comment: Eclipse also differentiates between the two (member variables are blue by default), so I would just keep your existing style unless you want to change every member variable in your app. For a new app, just go with whatever you/your team prefers and keep it consistent like Spidy said.